# OpenCV Segmentation fault for VideoCapture

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macports

I am using OpenCV2 with Python for a while and I don't why for a couple days it doesn't work for Video Capturing.
For example, this code works:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> a = cv2.imread('./pic_video0_145.jpg')
>>> a.shape
(416, 576, 3)
```

But it doesn't to capture video and exit from Python (or dead kernel in Jupyter Notebook):

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture('./video6.avi')
Segmentation fault: 11
```

It used to work and I don't remember to have changed something regarding OpenCV (perhaps an update of MacPorts).

**More information:**
I am working on Mac OS X 10.12
Version : 3.2.0
Installed with MacPorts : `opencv @3.2.0_1+contrib+debug+python35+qt4+tbb (active)`

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: have you tried with another video? or with the webcam? maybe reinstalling opencv?

Comment: Yes, I tried with multiple videos from Jupyter Notebook, launched from script and iPython. No, I didn't try with the webcam because I don't use it at all. I would rather no reinstalling openCV, except if it's the only solution ...

Comment: did it work or fail with the other videos? usually that segmentation fault is about out of bounds memory access.... so it could be a bug, or maybe some codec problem?

Comment: No, it failed with the other videos ... 
I just tried with a short video and 8gb of free memory and I still have the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I uninstalled and reinstalled OpenCV2 with MacPorts (proper installation).

```
sudo uninstall opencv
sudo port install opencv +debug +python35 +qt4 +tbb +contrib 

# To use openCV in a virtual env
cp /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so VIRTUALENV_PATH/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
```

I needed to update numpy too (`pip install numpy -U`) and it worked.